# how to sort a database

Tags: database, sorting, python-3.x

I have a database that i now combined using this function

```
def ReadAndMerge():
    library1=input("Enter 1st filename to read and merge:")
    with open(library1, 'r') as library1names:
        library1contents = library1names.read()
    library2=input("Enter 2nd filename to read and merge:")
    with open(library2, 'r') as library2names:
        library2contents = library2names.read()

    print(library1contents)
    print(library2contents)
    combined_contents = library1contents + library2contents  # concatenate text

    print(combined_contents)
    return(combined_contents)
```

The two databases originally looked like this

```
Bud Abbott 51 92.3
Mary Boyd 52 91.4
Hillary Clinton 50 82.1
```

and this

```
Don Adams 51 90.4
Jill Carney 53 76.3
Randy Newman 50 41.2
```

After being combined they now look like this

```
Bud Abbott 51 92.3
Mary Boyd 52 91.4
Hillary Clinton 50 82.1
Don Adams 51 90.4
Jill Carney 53 76.3
Randy Newman 50 41.2
```

if i wanted to sort this database by last names how would i go about doing that?
is there a sort function built in to python like lists? is this considered a list?
or would i have to use another function that locates the last name then orders them alphabetically

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: i dont know if i understand what you are asking, i am new to coding, so i am sorry if i used the wrong term.  they are just .txt files that are saved on my computer

Comment: Sorry my bad I thought you were using some database. I have updated my answer

Comment: Although strictly correct, calling a file with data a "database" will confuse most people, as a "database" usually is used for software designed to handle, index and search in large sets of data. Hence, you do not have a database. You only have a file with data.

Answer (score 2):

You sort with the `sorted()` method. But you can't sort just a big string, you need to have the data in a list or something similar. Something like this (untested):

```
def get_library_names(): # Better name of function
    library1 = input("Enter 1st filename to read and merge:")
    with open(library1, 'r') as library1names:
        library1contents = library1names.readlines()
    library2=input("Enter 2nd filename to read and merge:")
    with open(library2, 'r') as library2names:
        library2contents = library2names.readlines()

    print(library1contents)
    print(library2contents)
    combined_contents = sorted(library1contents + library2contents)

    print(combined_contents)
    return(combined_contents)
```

Comment: better yet, put those lines into objects. (Name: "Bud Abbott", SomeNumber: 51, SomeFloat: 92.3)

Comment: @crapman: That's the next step. Crawl before you walk, etc. :-)

Comment: your answer sorted every individual character i had it turned my group of names and numbers into this ['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '9', '9', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'H', 'J', 'M', 'N', 'R', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i] there is more but it wont all fit

Comment: @spenman: No it did not. You missed the change from `read()` to `readlines()`.